# Matplotlib plots not displaying in sublimetext

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext2

I've recently started using sublimetext 2, however I noticed today that the `plt.show()` function doesn't seem to work when run within sublimetext.

If for example I create the following script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

Running this with IDLE generates a plot, however using sublimetext no output is generated. It just keeps 'thinking' until I end the python.exe process after which [Finished] is output.

Have I misunderstood how sublimetext is meant to be used?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you executing the script in Sublime Text? What platform are you on?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I simply hit f5.

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3 build 3156 on Windows (and version 3143 on CentOS). The code works fine on both system. The image windows is shown after we press `Ctrl+B` to execute the script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess would be that Sublime Text 2 launches your code in its own environment, and only traps and displays the console output. The same problem exists when using GUI's, such as wxPython.

Another work around is to open the command prompt and launch it manually (python file.py).

**EDIT:** [Here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) it states that "Under Windows, GUIs are supressed."

**EDIT 2:** [Here](http://ptomato.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/geek-tip-running-python-guis-in-sublime-text-2/) it lists a way to fix it, right at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me after hours of Googling!

Answer (score 17):

More appropriate way is to just add one line in default Python build system file:

```
"shell": true
```

Or make additional Python build system with:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

Comment: It works for me but in windows I get the following message:
    CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
    UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

The problem is now time to time the build crashes the editor

Comment: For windows the  file variable must be inside brackets as: "cmd": ["python", "-u", "${file}"], this way you avoid to get the UNC path warning.

Comment: `"shell": true` worked for me

Answer (score 11):

I tried out theta's answer as suggested above. It works fine. In case the console opens and closes instantly like running python files directly from file explorer, just add the following line at the end:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.show('hold')
```

Its my first time answering here. Sorry if I didn't adhere to the answer format.

Comment: this should be the right answer. It keeps plot window up, without modifying dev environment

Comment: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Passing the block parameter of show() positionally is deprecated since Matplotlib 3.1; the parameter will become keyword-only in 3.3.

Answer (score 10):

Note in sublime text 3 (with anaconda package installed)

You need to add a custom build system as theta said, by:

first add a folder named python in `\path\to\Sublime Text Build XXXX\Data\Packages`

then put a file named `python.sublime-build` into that folder.

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

and remember to add `plt.show()` like Roald said.

```
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue under Ubuntu. I was trying to plot a `pandas` `DataFrame` like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([*range(5)])
df.plot()
```

But the plot did not show. Turns out you need to do `plt.show()`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347145/pandas-plot-doesnt-show).