# Displaying pyplot Windows using Anaconda+Sublime

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext2, anaconda

I installed the Anaconda distribution on Windows and got it working with Sublime Text 2. Now I can press ctrl+B to run scripts and after using pip to install the required packages, I finally have no ImportErrors. Unfortunately Matplotlib plots will not display no matter what I do.

The most promising-looking answer was one on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831882/matplotlib-plots-not-displaying-in-sublimetext). I edited %appdata%\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Python\Python.sublime-build to look like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Anaconda\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

However it did nothing, and putting quotes around "true" made no difference.

I was used to calling "ipython --pylab" in the console to enable Pyplot windows, so I tried editing the first line to the following:

```
"cmd": ["C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\ipython.exe", "--pylab", "$file"]
```

In %AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User, I also tried commenting out the line:

```
// startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

Not sure what else to try now. Has anyone encountered and solved this before?

Thanks!

Comment: problem solved. In the end it was simply solved by adding a line in my own code:

`matplotlib.pylab.show(block=False)`

I hadn't needed this before so I don't now why I do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the OP's comment:

> problem solved. In the end it was simply solved by adding a line in my
>   own code:

```
matplotlib.pylab.show(block=False)
```