# Pandas plot doesn't show

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When using this in a script (not IPython), nothing happens, i.e. the plot window doesn't appear :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts.plot()
```

Even when adding `time.sleep(5)`, there is still nothing. Why?

Is there a way to do it, **without having to manually call matplotlib** ?

Comment: Do you get any output from `ts.plot()`?

Comment: what do you mean "manually call matplotlib"?  the usual way is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, `plt.show()`

Comment: @itzy : nothing happens when `ts.plot()`, the program terminates immediately after this. Even if I add `time.sleep(10)` nothing is displayed

Comment: @maxymoo : I thought that doing `.plot()` on a panda object would handle everything for me (i.e. pandas does the matplotlib job, instead of me) : see [this example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot).

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Once you have made your plot, you need to tell matplotlib to `show` it. The usual way to do things is to import `matplotlib.pyplot` and call `show` from there:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts.plot()
plt.show()
```

In older versions of `pandas`, you were able to find a backdoor to matplotlib, as in the example below. **NOTE: This no longer works in modern versions of `pandas`**, and I still recommend importing matplotlib separately, as in the example above.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts.plot()
pd.tseries.plotting.pylab.show()
```

But all you are doing there is finding somewhere that `matplotlib` has been imported in `pandas`, and calling the same `show` function from there.

Are you trying to avoid calling `matplotlib` in an effort to speed things up? If so then you are really not speeding anything up, since `pandas` already imports `pyplot`:

```
python -mtimeit -s 'import pandas as pd'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0122 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s 'import pandas as pd; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0125 usec per loop
```

Finally, the reason the [example you linked in comments](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot) doesn't need the call to `matplotlib` is because it is being run interactively in an `iPython notebook`, not in a script.

Comment: When I run 'pd.tseries.plotting.pylab.show()' I get "padnas.tseries' has no attribute plotting, is it outdated? You did write that in 2015..

Comment: Yes, it looks like that back door to matplotlib is no longer there. I still recommend the first option anyway

Comment: Thanks. I think the API design could be better. It is odd we need to know about matplotlib to use panda.plot

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using `matplotlib,` and still, things don't show up in iPython notebook (or Jupyter Lab as well) remember to set the inline option for `matplotlib` in the notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
```

Then the following code will work flawlessly:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9));
change_per_ins.plot(ax=ax, kind='hist')
```

If you don't set the inline option it won't show up and by adding a `plt.show()` in the end you will get duplicate outputs.

Answer (score 2):

I did just

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
```

and add line

```
plt.show()
```

next to df.plot() and it worked well for

Comment: Please include which environment you use to be able to insert `%matplotlib inline` (this is not standard Python that can be used in a script).

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` is used in ipython/jupyter notebook...

Comment: Yeah, there is no need to add %matplotlib inline if you are using an IDE like pycharm(I've been using it).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers involve importing `matplotlib.pyplot` and/or calling some second function manually.

Instead, you can configure `matplotlib` to be in [interactive mode](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode) with its [configuration files](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file).

Simply add the line

`interactive: True`

to a file called `matplotlibrc` in one of the following places:

- In the current working directory
- In the platform specific user directory specified by `matplotlib.get_configdir()`

  - On unix-like system, typically `/home/username/.config/matplotlib/`
  - On Windows `C:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\.matplotlib\\`