# Pandas DataFrame.hist() doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i follow the google course about machine learning. i'm on this part : [pandas](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/intro_to_pandas.ipynb?hl=fr#scrollTo=nqndFVXVlbPN)

But on my mac when i want to generate a chart with this command :

```
california_housing_dataframe.hist('housing_median_age')
```

it doesn't work. The python icon appear but nothing is displaying on the screen.

i have see some tips with the backend parameter into matplotlibrc but mine is equals to MacOSX and it should work ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you post what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I haven't any error. The python icon appear as the chart try to be display. But no window appear.

Comment: have you tried calling the matplotlib `.show()` method?

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347145/pandas-plot-doesnt-show)

Answer (score 25):

You need to call **`plt.show()`**. This worked for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
california_housing_dataframe.hist('housing_median_age')
plt.show()
```

(to elaborate on the comment from T. Kelly).

Answer (score 7):

I'm following Google ML Crash Course(I think you are also following it based on the variable name).

I too encountered the same problem.

When I call

```
california_housing_dataframe.hist('housing_median_age')
```

It is not showing any histogram. Instead it is showing

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x12bb814e0>]],
  dtype=object)
```

To show the histogram, add this line in your imports:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

It should show the histogram.