# Why doesn't Visual Studio Code show my graph?

Tags: pandas, plot, visual-studio-code, subplot

I have the following code but my graphs never show up in Visual Studio Code. It will show on a jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
DAX[['Close','Return']].plot(subplots=True,style='b',figsize=(8,5))
```

Why?
[image: This is what it is supposed to show]

Comment: you need to call show(). from matplotlib.pyplot as plt    plt.show()

Comment: Im not exactly using matplotlib though. I am just using pandas.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think with the newer version of pandas matplotlib is the only way to get the plots show up via IDEs. Also this post might be useful to go through - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347145/pandas-plot-doesnt-show

Comment: did you figure this out?  i can get it to show w/ matplotlib, but not using pandas_datareader