# Reading JSON in a format that can be plotted

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to read a JSON file generated from a `dict()` such that I can then make a pie chart. My code so far:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

openJson = open("path")

jsonFile = json.load(openJson)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jsonFile)
```

The problem I have is that I can't even try plotting the graph because I cant convert the JSON to a data frame. The error I get is `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`. I also tried writing `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jsonFile, index=[0])` as found in a similar post, but it seems that `index` is an unexpected argument.

How can I read that JSON so it can be plotted?

LE: Added JSON file called `category.json`

```
{"Restaurants": 678.7800000000001, "Utilities": 807.26, "Services": 35.67, "Transport": 1295.65, "Shopping": 1454.15, "Groceries": 1162.89}
```

Comment: What does the Json look like

Comment: @ifly6 I have edited my post to add the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('data.json') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(f),index=[0])
print(df)
```

output

```
   Restaurants  Utilities  ...  Shopping  Groceries
0       678.78     807.26  ...   1454.15    1162.89

[1 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: sorry for reaching out again, but I tried e simple pie chart plot `df.plot(subplots=True, kind='pie')` but nothing shows. Weirdly, PyCharm displays no error.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347145/pandas-plot-doesnt-show

Answer (score 1):

Read JSON file like this

```
df = pd.read_json (r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\data.json')
```

This will work if your file is already in JSON format.

Comment: Somehow I get the same error, so it doesn't work, unfortunately. What else can I try?

Comment: Follow this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe