# python pandas dataframe.plot()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I am working on assignment and I am having trouble. When I run the program it compiles and there are no errors. however, nothing is printed out on the terminal screen. I guess I expect a graph on the terminal screen but don't see anything

```
with open('myfile.csv') as csvfile:
data = pd.read_csv(csvfile, delimiter=',')

d = data.values
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dd.plot()
```

Any tips or suggestions is appreciated

Comment: You're missing `plt.show()` Refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347145/pandas-plot-doesnt-show#34354149)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('myfile.csv') as csvfile:
   data = pd.read_csv(csvfile, delimiter=',')

   d = data.values
   dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   dd.plot()
   plt.show()
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

The graph is plotting with your current code as is,

Please check the imports once again. I'm using the following imports:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```