# IPython does not show plots within Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, ipython, sublimetext3

When using the interactive IPython console using SublimeREPL within Sublime Text 3, matplotlib plots do not appear (even after running the command plt.show()). I have also noticed that windows created with Tkinter do not appear. This problem does not occur when I am using IPython from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10832619/5792352

Also, I had the same problem in Notepad++ using the NppExec plugin to display output in Notepad++'s own console and solved it by defining the following execute command in NppExec:

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
NPP_RUN ipython -i $(FILE_NAME)
```

Maybe something similar is possible in Sublime Text?

Comment: I have tried the fix mentioned in the linked question but haven't had any luck. Plots do show up when running a script using the default Python build, but not in IPython within Sublime.