# Cannot install Github download

Tags: python, matplotlib, github, sublimetext3, setup.py

I cannot install matplotlib. I do not know what to do. I also do not know how to handle the GitHub installer. I 'cloned,' but do not know how to install it. Can you help me out?

I want to use it with Sublime Text 3 (Python is already installed).

```
C:\Users\T>cd matplotlib
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\T>python -mpip install .
Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
```

Comment: If you are trying to use it with Sublime I would consider looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10832619/3990806). More generally given you aren't even in the directory of the cloned code base you aren't going to find the `setup.py`. You need to find where you cloned it to and be in that to even install.

Comment: Note that usually you do not need to install the development version. Rather use pip to install, i.e. `python -mpip install matplotlib`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me.