# Matplotlib plots not showing up in SublimeText 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext3

The question is similar to one previously asked ([Matplotlib plots not displaying in sublimetext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831882/matplotlib-plots-not-displaying-in-sublimetext)), but the solution given is for SublimeText2 and is not working for me for SublimeText3.

My question is essentially the same. Using the example code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = x

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

will give me a plot that shows up when using an IDE, or running it in terminal, but I cannot get it to show up in SublimeText. The code will continue to run unless I manually cancel the build, but runs fine if `plt.show()` is commented out (the plot does not show of course).

Will I have to use something other than sublime text to achieve this. Running on Windows 10 as well.

Thanks.

EDIT

Screenshots of what happens when trying to run:

[image: When trying to run the code, the plt.plot() runs fine but it will just continue to run after the print statement until I force it to cancel, with no graph shown]

[image: When plt.show() is removed, the code will run successfully but again no graph shown.]

When trying to run the code, the plt.plot() runs fine but it will just continue to run after the print statement until I force it to cancel, with no graph shown

When plt.show() is removed, the code will run successfully but again no graph shown.

Using `plt.savefig()` will save the graph, no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

Mine works fine. Is there an error message? I suggest installing the latest version of sublime i think

Also is python been set to your environment variables? I suggest that too

Then after that is go to Tools->Build System->(check)Python

[image]

Comment: I've amended by original question to include screenshots of what happens. No error message being displayed, it will just continue to run until cancelled. My build system is working fine and have had no issue with running any other code, and my sublime is on the latest version. Not really sure what's going on, running on Windows if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda with ST3, then you can:

1. Go to Preferences -> Package Settings -> Conda -> Settings
2. In the User settings add: { "run_through_shell":true }
3. Instead of using plt.show(), use plt.show(block=True) (the former will not hold the figure, it will close immediately)

This was with Windows 10.